# Woocommerce / Sensei overwrite a variable or function in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, filter, woocommerce

I'm working on a website that is using Woocommerce (and its plugin Sensei, which supports courses, lessons, quizzes, etc.). I'm running into trouble changing a small piece of info.

Within the Sensei plugin there if a file (woothemes-sensei > includes > class-sensei-course.php). In this file, there is one line of code that I want to change without editing the core file. I understand that I probably need to do this in my child theme's functions.php files, but I'm not quite sure what to do. I need to change the $course_page_url to a custom url in the following code:

```
 <div id="active-courses">

            <?php if ( '' != $active_html ) {

                echo $active_html;

            } else { ?>

                <div class="sensei-message info">

                    <?php echo $no_active_message; ?>

                    <a href="<?php echo $course_page_url; ?>">

                        <?php  _e( 'Start a Course!', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?>

                    </a>

                </div>

            <?php } // End If Statement ?>

        </div>
```

Can anyone tell me the best way to go about doing that? I don't know how to hook into a filter to change that url.

And the entire class-sensei-course.php file can be found [here](https://github.com/Automattic/sensei/blob/master/includes/class-sensei-course.php). The code that I included above begins on line 1596.

Comment: Have you checked the sensei settings? You should be able to set a specific page in the settings, if this is not what you want then please let us know what you want to achieve, you want to redirect to outside link? or something else?

Comment: I haven't found anything in the settings that would change it.All I want to do is change $course_page_url (which is a default woocommerce shop page, in this case) to myurl/shop (this is a custom shop page that I have created).